# Could not find __Truffle__NotFound.sol from any sources

Tags: contract-development, truffle, truffle-compile

This is the [file](https://gist.github.com/PaulRBerg/dcf8696e9e115e450a890f4fc959790f) I'm trying to compile.

I've been using truffle for a few years and I remember that we used to be able to compile files with different names than the contracts inside.

I'm using truffle 5.0.35. Is this no longer the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind, the issue was that I had a missing bracket at the end of the contract. It is possible to compile files with different contract names with truffle (not possible with [sol-compiler](https://sol-compiler.com) though).